Usando a lib leaflet react, estou tentando mostrar um marker no mapa porém a imagem não renderiza
Meu projeto esta sendo feito em next, e acho que esse seja o problema pois ja usei essa lib em outro projeto que nao era feito em next. A documentação recomenda apenas que chame o marker que ele vai aparecer mas fiz e não apreceu, então fui atras de soluções, até baixei um icone e coloquei para ser ele a imagem mas mesmo assim não funcionou.
Segue o código:
import { useQueryGetCoordinates } from '@/hooks/Mapas/useQueryGetCoordinates';
import { LatLngExpression, icon } from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { LayerGroup, LayersControl, MapContainer, Marker, Polyline, Popup, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';

interface MapProps {
    insp: number;
}

function Map({ insp }: MapProps) {
    const [coord, setCoord] = useState<LatLngExpression[]>([]);
    const { data: coordinatesData, isPending } = useQueryGetCoordinates(insp);
    console.log(coordinatesData);

    const ICON = icon({
        iconUrl: require('../../img/marker.png'),
        iconSize: [32, 32],
    })

    const teste: LatLngExpression[] = [
        [-22.910926741060408, -43.19286176086815],
        [-22.91010964046485, -43.191462905955476],
        [-22.909543952552223, -43.19043935358034],
        [-22.908286859851383, -43.18607219677979],
        [-22.906118347548592, -43.18719810439244],
        [-22.904515511817674, -43.18317213171693],
        [-22.90280531155429, -43.1839707237395],
        [-22.90706367215745, -43.19755992678968],
        [-22.90326031719855, -43.19892654085509]
    ];

    useEffect(() => {
        if (coordinatesData && coordinatesData.length > 0) {
            const lines: LatLngExpression[] = coordinatesData.map((item: any) => [item.latitude, item.longitude]);
            setCoord(lines);
        } else {
            setCoord([]);
        }
    }, [coordinatesData]);

    return (
        <div className='w-full h-full'>
            <p className='font-bold'>{insp == 0 ? null : isPending && 'Carregando...'}</p>
            <MapContainer
                center={[-22.92140814475, -43.21347931399]}
                zoom={12}
                scrollWheelZoom={false}
                style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', borderRadius: '10px' }}
            >
                <LayerGroup>
                    <LayersControl position='bottomright'>
                        <LayersControl.BaseLayer checked name='OpenStreetMap'>
                            <TileLayer
                                noWrap={true}
                                attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                                url="https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/osm_bright/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png"
                            />
                        </LayersControl.BaseLayer>
                    </LayersControl>
                </LayerGroup>
                {coord.length > 0 && (
                    <>
                        <Polyline pathOptions={{ color: 'red' }} positions={teste} />  {/* positions certa vem do coord */}
                        <Marker position={teste[0]} icon={ICON}>
                            <Popup>Começo da inspeção</Popup>
                        </Marker>
                        <Marker position={teste[teste.length - 1]} icon={ICON}>
                            <Popup>Fim da inspeção</Popup>
                        </Marker>
                    </>
                )}
            </MapContainer>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Map;


Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Encontrei a solução:
import markerIcon2x from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png';
import markerIcon from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png';
import markerShadow from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png';

adicionei as importações para buscar diretamente da lib e passei elas em um objeto para que seja o padrão
const DefaultIcon = L.icon({
    iconRetinaUrl: markerIcon2x.src,
    iconUrl: markerIcon.src,
    shadowUrl: markerShadow.src,
    iconAnchor: [12, 39],
    shadowAnchor: [12, 41],
    popupAnchor: [1, -34]
});
L.Marker.prototype.options.icon = DefaultIcon;

precisei fazer alguns ajustes pois veio com erro na posição dos markers, por isso o IconAnchor
